# Unclear malloc error: sysmalloc Assertion failed

Tags: c, malloc, glibc

The following error:

```
malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

occurs when I perform the following malloc:

```
typedef struct chamber_in_s {
    pthread_t hthread;
    midi_out_ports_t midi_out_ports;
} chamber_in_t;

memset(&chamber_in, 0x00, sizeof(chamber_in));
if (!(chamber_in.midi_out_ports.port = malloc(count * sizeof(*chamber_in.midi_out_ports.port)))) {
        log_error(MYNAME "startChamberIn malloc failed for &i bytes\n",
            count * sizeof(*chamber_in.midi_out_ports.port));
        return -1;
    }
```

The error only appears when I malloc some previous, unrelated data structures first. The error also only occurs on a newer version of Debian, as it worked fine on Debian jessie. I have tried doubling the amount of memory requested by malloc in case it is a not-enough-space-requested problem, but the error persists.

The malloc.c used by my glibc is here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.31/source/malloc/malloc.c

Any ideas on what this error means and how to solve it?

EDIT: valgrind does not bring up any errors

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Sounds like you're exceeding the bounds of previously allocated memory (probably an array) and clobbering malloc's metadata.

Comment: Sidenote: `memset(&chamber_in, 0x00, sizeof(chamber_in));` could probably have been replaced by zeroing it at the definition: `type chamber_in = {0};`

Comment: I forgot to add, valgrind does not show any errors, though maybe it is not well equipped to deal with processes that create side threads.

Comment: @sj95126 so what you're suggesting is there is an overflow *before* the malloc call, that messes up this call?

Comment: @Cheetaiean: It's a possibility. As dbush said, valgrind may help you identify where.

Comment: You are right - in a function before the malloc I was overflowing a previously allocated segment of memory. I don't know why valgrind didn't catch this, but glad I figured it out.